# Using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to know whether an app can be a BroadcastReceiver and sender? Please expain with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Application can't be a BroadcastReceiver. BroadcastReceiver is an application component. But answer to your question is yes: you can send broadcasts from one component and receive it in another.

For ex. in activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

In receiver:

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // here is your intent
 }
```

Comment: Since you can get your hand on a context, you can also send a broadcast from a BroadcastReceiver. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: How will be Manifest of such app which is a sender and receiver too. I only know about `<receiver>`. Do we have to add something for sending also?

Comment: No, you don't need to. The only thing neccessary is `<receiver>` spec.

Comment: As I've to deal with a **custom broadcaster**, so what should I put in  `android:name`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. An example can be found [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/).

Answer (score 1):

If by app you mean activity, so yes you can but you will have to embed your `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity and register/unregister it yourself. That way, you just need to add your activity as `Activity` in the Manifest and you activity will be able to receive a broadcast and send broadcast as well.

I m not too sure how it behaves in term of life cycle though. You will need to look it up if it s what you want.